# Check if buckets of items can be placed in an interleaved manner

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

bucket1 = [1,2,3,4]

bucket2 = [5,6]

bucket3 = [7,8,9,10,11]

bucket4 = [12]

Need to place them in an arrangement such that 3 consecutive elements in the arrangement should be from 3 different buckets.

eg: 5,7,12,1,6,8,2,9.. Since bucket2 and bucket4 elements are used up, it is not possible to do so.

So to generalise

There are buckets B0 to Bn each having number of elements C0 to Cn, check if it is possible to arrange in an interleaved manner such that X consecutive elements in the arrangement should be from X different buckets.

Comment: But your example is actually proving it is possible. There are 3 items from different buckets in consecutively arranged consecutively. You should clarify what you mean.

Comment: You don't actually ask a question here.

Comment: @Paul - 3 is also a constraint here. 3 consecutive elements should be from 3 different buckets. So once bucket4 and bucket2 elements are exhausted and other 2 buckets has elements left to be arranged, then it becomes impossible. I will edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: @Richard - This was a question asked to me in an interview recently. I have tried solving it myself, but could not. Hence thought of asking the community. Can you please suggest what I could have done better with this?

Comment: @hari: I'm sorry, I tried to edit your question to increase its clarity, but was unable to do so because it's unclear to me what the question is. At the minimum, though, any question should have a question mark (`?`), and yours does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if no bucket has more than floor((x + 2) / 3) items, where x is the total number of items.

For x=1,2,3 it is clear that it is possible if no bucket has more than 1 item.

For x > 3 consider the bucket with most items and start with its item, and so on twice more, using different buckets. There must be at least three different buckets to make up x. Now you have reduced x by three and used up one item from each bucket near the limit. Furthermore the largest bucket can be used again, so you can pretty much start from scratch - and by induction the problem is solvable.

If any bucket has more than floor((x + 2) / 3) there are too many to fit into the sequence, even if you can use that pattern X ? ? X ? ? .... ? ? X.

Comment: What is the significance of 2 here in ((x+2)/3) ?

Comment: In ((x+2) /3) , what is 2 and what is 3? If i take 3 as number of different consecutive, and 2 as 3-1 and apply the following buckets bucket1 = [1,2,3,4], bucket2 = [5,6], bucket3 = [7,8,9,10], bucket4 = [12] , It would be ((4+2+4+1)+2)/3 = 4. Max number of elements in the bucket is 4, but still these buckets cannot be arranged with 3 consecutive elements from 3 different buckets.

Comment: I think I have the sequence 1 7 5 2 8 6 3 9 12 4 10

Comment: right.. I was thinking that it should complete exactly in multiples of 3. But you are right. This satisfies the conditions mentioned in the question